# Sharepoint 2007: User name changed in ActiveDirectory. Old name still shown at top right of portal page

Tags: sharepoint-2007, active-directory

I now have 2 users whose names are not correctly displayed in the 'welcome' menu at the top right of the page.

The first user married and her surname changed. The new name was entered in ActiveDirectory but her maiden name is still displayed.

In the second case, a LAN id was reallocated to a new department member. The name of the previous user is displayed in the portal.

The AD synchronising appears to be running every night and I can see no errors there. The AD entries for the 2 users appears correct and no hint of the previous data.

What else can I do to force an update of the user information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have experenced this before, on the  Microsoft blogs there is this helpful post

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/krichie/archive/2006/02/18/534767.aspx

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

This kind of information is stored in the content database's [UserInfo table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd588089%28office.11%29.aspx). [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spfargo/archive/2009/02/13/guidance-user-info-synch-in-moss-2007.aspx) may be useful to you.

Keep in mind that changing the data in the UserInfo table directly is not supported. If you still want to edit this manually, you'll have to use the object model.

Answer (score 1):

No need to change data directly OR manually update the SQL table.
When you remove the user from any group, this also removes the user from the userInfo table in the Microsoft SQL Server database. 
When you re-add the user, the user's information is automatically updated in this table.

Answer (score 0):

1. check the effective permission of user/group by accessing the portal URL link, click on site actions --> site settings -->check effective permissions
2. make sure to note down the effective permission for user/group without fail
3. click on all people link above site permissions and search for the user/group name which should still be displaying old name
4. remove the user/group name from all people
5. add the user/group name to the required group as per note done in step no. 2
6. now if user close the browser (refresh the page) and re-login new diaply name would be displayed